# Encrypt/Decryption RSA communication Java-PHP

Tags: java, php, rsa

I'm trying to implement a client-server communication encrypted with RSA.
I generate private and public key pairs in java then I pass some inputs to a PHP script through `GET` parameters. If there is only the key set as `GET` parameter the script encrypts a phrase that will be decrypted from the client (by java) otherwise if it's set a message (the m parameters see the PHP script) it should be able to decrypt it.

I coded the following:

java:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Generate public and private keys using RSA
        Map<String, Object> keys = getRSAKeys();

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keys.get("private");
        PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) keys.get("public");

        StringBuilder keypublic = new StringBuilder();

        keypublic.append("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
        keypublic.append(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()) + "\n");
        keypublic.append("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");

        StringBuilder keyprivate = new StringBuilder();

        keypublic.append("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
        keypublic.append(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()) + "\n");
        keypublic.append("-----END PRIVATE  KEY-----\n");


        String keyEncodedPublic = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keypublic.toString().getBytes());
        String keyEncodedPrivate = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keypublic.toString().getBytes());

        String signature = sign("MyEncryptedInternalString", privateKey);
        //Offuscare la MyEncryptedInternalString in qualche modo
        System.out.println("key: \n" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature.getBytes()) + ":" + 
                                                     keyEncodedPublic);


        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println("Crypted: \n" +  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptMessage("hello", privateKey).getBytes()));
        //System.out.println("Verified? " + verify("test",signature,publicKey));

        while(true) {

            Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Insert text: ");
            String enc = out.nextLine();


            String descryptedText = decryptMessage(enc, privateKey);
            System.out.println("Decrypted: " + descryptedText);
            System.out.println();

        }



    }


    public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

        return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }

    public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }


    // Get RSA keys. Uses key size of 2048.
    private static Map<String,Object> getRSAKeys() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        keys.put("private", privateKey);
        keys.put("public", publicKey);
        return keys;
    }

    // Decrypt using RSA public key
    private static String decryptMessage(String encryptedText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText)));
    }


    // Encrypt using RSA private key
    private static String encryptMessage(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
    }
```

And the PHP script:

```
<?php    

  function RSAEncryptMessage($string, $key){
      $data = "MyEncryptedInternalString";
      $parts = explode(":",$key);
      $signature = base64_decode($parts[0]);
      $pubkeyid = $parts[1];
      $ok = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), base64_decode($pubkeyid), "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
      if ($ok == 1){
          $pubkeyid = base64_decode($pubkeyid);
          openssl_public_encrypt($string, $crypted, $pubkeyid);
      }
      return base64_encode($crypted);
  }

  function RSADecryptMessage($string, $key){
      $data = "MyEncryptedInternalString";
      $parts = explode(":",$key);
      $signature = base64_decode($parts[0]);
      $pubkeyid = $parts[1];
      //$ok = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), base64_decode($pubkeyid), "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
      $pubkeyid = base64_decode($pubkeyid);
      openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $decrypted, $pubkeyid);
      echo "Decrypted text: ". $decrypted;
      return $decrypted;
  }

  $mex = "hello";
  //echo RSAEncryptMessage($m,$_GET['key']);
  if(isset($_GET['m'])){
    echo RSADecryptMessage($_GET['m'],$_GET['key']);
  }else{
    echo RSAEncryptMessage($mex,$_GET['key']);
  }
?>
```

So when I try to encrypt the content by server-side and then decrypting it in Java it works correctly. I'm assuming to use the generated public key to encrypt the content (sending it to the server) and decrypting the content by using the stored private key on the client too.
[image]

The question:
I'm not able to do the contrary: encrypt by client-side and decrypting by server-side using the PHP function `RSADecryptMessage`. When passing the parameters it doesn't work and writes nothing.

EDIT:
Since I need a communication both sides encrypted to avoid MITM attacks, for example, I use PUBLICKEY generated by the client, then I send the key to the server. So I encrypt my message from the server using the same public key. In this way, from the client, I'm able to decrypt the response by the server using the private key. The best way would be which server generates both public and private key pairs but unfortunately, Java is not able to decrypt a message if the key pair is generated and shared by PHP and that's why I allow the client to generate the key pair. This works. Now I need to do the contrary too, with the same public key sent previously to the server I need to decrypt a message encrypted by the client this time (in the image you can see the string "crypted"). Unfortunately, this seems not to work, because when I call the PHP script, the content is not decrypted.

Comment: You are encrypting the message in java with the private key, but you should encrypt the message with the public key. It currently works because the private key "contains" the public key, but in a realistic scenario you don't have the private key, it will never leave the system where it was created.

Comment: @Progman I changed `encryptMessage("hello", privateKey)` with `encryptMessage("hello", publicKey)` but still doesn't work

Comment: Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Also use base64url for encoding the byte array. The base64 encoding can contain characters, which might be problematic when placed directly in an URL.

Comment: @Progman the behaviour it's the same... no text is decrypted by the PHP script and nothing is shown

Comment: @Progman normally I use `URLEncoder.encode` after an base64 encoding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224263/discussion-between-virgula-and-progman).

Comment: Please [edit] your question on how you send the data between java and PHP. Explain in detail which part of the keys you are sending/using where. It looks like you are sending the key from the java side to the PHP side, which looks strange is most likely not what you should do. Also, it looks like you are trying to decrypt a message with the public key (based on the naming of the variables). Each party should generate its own key and send (only) the public key to the other party.

Comment: @Progman I edited, I hope to have improved the question.

Comment: You can't use the public key to decrypt a message. The public key can only be used for "encrypt" and "verify", the private key is the only one which can be used for "decrypt" and "sign". When you want to send an encrypted message from PHP to java, you have to use the public key generated from java (server), not php (client). Keep in mind, both parties generate their own public-private-key-pair and send the public key to the other party. The server does not generate the public-private-key-pair for the client, the client does that on its own.

Comment: Your message "unfortunately, Java is not able to decrypt a message if the key pair is generated and shared by PHP" is not reproducible on my system. I'm generating a RSA keypair on PHP-side, encrypt the data on PHP-side with the public key and decrypt the encrypted data on Java side with the private key generated on my PHP system. As the private key is in PEM encoding I do a simple conversion to a Java PrivateKey and use this key for decryption.

Comment: @MichaelFehr really? Can you share the code?

Comment: @Virgula: just to be for sure: The workflow is to 1) generate a RSA keypair on PHP, 2) send the public key to Java, 3) encrypt data with the public key received on Java, 4) send the ciphertext to PHP, 5) decrypt the data with the private key on PHP. The other point is: your Java code seems to **sign** the data instead of **encrypt** - that may explain the mixture of private-public key usage. So what is your Java code to encrypt?

Comment: @Progman yes what you wrote is correct but remember that the application should be able to do the reverse of what you wrote too (so decrypt what php sends because communication should be fully encrypted and both sides should be able to encrypt/decrypt the content of the other side). In Java there is a method called encryptMessage (shown in the original post) which I’m trying to use to encrypt the data. I used signing method because it seems the only way to make the obfuscation of message by client and decryption by php working. While the reverse of this does not work in any way.

Comment: @Virgula When you want to send an encrypted message from PHP to Java, PHP will have to encrypt it with the public key **from Java**. Then Java will decrypt it with his private key. When you want to send an encrypted message from Java to PHP, Java will have to encrypt it the public key **from PHP**. Then PHP will decrypt it with his private key. Both parties generate their own key-pair and send the public-key to the other party. Btw.: Signing does not encrypt the message, the message will still be visible/readable.

Comment: @Progman that’s exactly what I want to realize! The public key pair will be exchanged to each other endpoint before to start the real communication. A well done example which does what you described will be appreciated because I was only able to do a part of the process.

Comment: @Virgula Your PHP script does not generate a key-pair, but it has to. After PHP has created a key-pair, you have to send the public-key of that key-pair from PHP to Java, so Java can encrypt a message for PHP. Exchanging the public-keys is a one time action, after that you only send encrypted messages, not keys. One public-key is only use for one communication direction of encrypted messages, not for both directions.

Comment: @Progman the problem is that I already tried to generate keys with php (in my example is not mentioned but I tried). I’ll try again and I’ll notice here

Comment: @Progman finally I was able to solve. I'll provide the solution in the original post. You need some copy and paste paying attention to passing the correct GET parameters to the PHP script to test it. Thank you, your tips were very important

Comment: @Virgula You can add it as an answer to your own question (and marked is as "accepted" as well).

Comment: May be a silly question but why not just run all communication over https ?

Comment: @apokryfos it can be used for servers which don’t support TLS/SSL (if you don’t want to pay certificates) or you can use it in localhost as a proxy with a communication encrypted. You can use it for several other situations too, or just for learning something new (my case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

> When you want to send an encrypted message from PHP to Java, PHP will
> have to encrypt it with the public key from Java. Then Java will
> decrypt it with his private key. When you want to send an encrypted
> message from Java to PHP, Java will have to encrypt it the public key
> from PHP. Then PHP will decrypt it with his private key. Both parties
> generate their own key-pair and send the public-key to the other
> party. Btw.: Signing does not encrypt the message, the message will
> still be visible/readable.

Comment of @Progman

Code.

java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Generate public and private keys using RSA
    Map<String, Object> keys = getRSAKeys();

    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keys.get("private");
    PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) keys.get("public");

    StringBuilder keypublic = new StringBuilder();

    keypublic.append("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
    keypublic.append(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()) + "\n");
    keypublic.append("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");


    String keyEncodedPublic = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keypublic.toString().getBytes());

    String signature = sign("MyEncryptedInternalString", privateKey);
    System.out.println("key: \n" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature.getBytes()) + ":" + keyEncodedPublic);


    System.out.println("\n");
    
    while(true) {


        Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert text: ");
        String enc = out.nextLine();


        String descryptedText = decryptMessage(enc, privateKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + descryptedText);
        System.out.println();

        Scanner out2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert text2: ");
        String enc2 = out2.nextLine();

        byte[] decodedBytesKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(enc2);

        //String content = encryptMessage("message from the client", new String(decodedBytes));

        String publicKeyPEM = new String(decodedBytesKey)
                .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        PublicKey p = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

        System.out.println(encryptMessage("Message from client",p));

    }


}


public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
    publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

    return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
}

public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
    privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
}


// Get RSA keys. Uses key size of 2048.
private static Map<String,Object> getRSAKeys() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    keys.put("private", privateKey);
    keys.put("public", publicKey);
    return keys;
}


private static String decryptMessage(String encryptedText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText)));
}



private static String encryptMessage(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return URLEncoder.encode(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes())));
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  include ("utils/RSA.php");

  $config = array(
      "digest_alg" => "sha512",
      "private_key_bits" => 2048,
      "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
  );

  $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
  openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
  $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
  $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

  echo "PubKey: " . base64_encode($pubKey) ."<br>";
  echo "PrivateKey: " . base64_encode($privKey) .  "<br>";


  //echo "Encrypted: " . base64_encode($encrypted);


  function RSAEncryptMessage($string, $key){
      $data = "MyEncryptedInternalString";
      $parts = explode(":",$key);
      $signature = base64_decode($parts[0]);
      $pubkeyid = $parts[1];
      $ok = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), base64_decode($pubkeyid), "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
      if ($ok == 1){
          $pubkeyid = base64_decode($pubkeyid);
          openssl_public_encrypt($string, $crypted, $pubkeyid);
      }
      return base64_encode($crypted);
  }

  function RSADecryptMessage($encrypted, $key){
        //todo
        openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, base64_decode($key));
        echo "Decrypted: " . $decrypted;
  }

  if((isset($_GET['providemessage']))){
    echo RSADecryptMessage($_GET['m'],$_GET['key']);
  }else if (isset($_GET['getmessage'])){
    $mex = "Message from server";
    echo RSAEncryptMessage($mex,$_GET['key']);
  }
?>
```

Screenshots:

> [image]

> [image]